# how to find nearest lower and upper value of sp?

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel

Example:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Big] => 1.32
        [FAN_MODEL] => AFPV3G-500-2800
        [FAN_DIA] => 500
        [FAN_RPM] => 2800
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BigVALUE] => 26.00
        [FAN_CMH] => 10000
        [BigPEAK_POWER] => 800.00
        [Bigoutlet_velocity] => 14.15
        [velocity_pressure] => 12.253
        [Bigtotal_velocity] => 13.57
        [SP1] => 8
        [SP2] => 5
        [SP3] => 7
        [SP4] => 7
        [SP5] => 7
        [SP6] => 7
        [SP7] => 7
        [SP8] => 7
        [SP9] => 7
        [SP10] => 7
        [Bigtotal_eff] => 0.33
        [static_eff] => 0.03
        [BigBKW] => 1.120
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [STATIC_PRESSURE] => 0.34
        [FAN_DIA] => 630
        [FAN_RPM] => 1460
        [FAN_MODEL] => 
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE] => 25.00
        [FAN_CMH] => 10000
        [EQU_PEAK_POWER] => 3601.86
        [outlet_velocity] => 8.92
        [velocity_pressure] => 4.862
        [total_velocity] => 5.20
        [SP2] => 14
        [SP3] => 42
        [SP4] => 41
        [SP5] => 1
        [SP6] => 4
        [SP7] => 4
        [SP8] => 4
        [SP9] => 4
        [SP10] => 1
        [total_eff] => 0.29
        [static_eff] => 0.19
        [BKW] => 0.486
        [Big] => 3.86
        [BigVALUE] => 26.00
        [BigPEAK_POWER] => 360.19
        [Bigoutlet_velocity] => 8.92
        [Bigtotal_velocity] => 8.72
        [SP1] => 1
        [Bigtotal_eff] => 0.43
        [BigBKW] => 0.547
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [SP1] => 1
        [FAN_MODEL] => 
        [Big] => 3.86
        [FAN_DIA] => 630
        [FAN_RPM] => 1460
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BigVALUE] => 26.00
        [FAN_CMH] => 10000
        [BigPEAK_POWER] => 360.19
        [Bigoutlet_velocity] => 8.92
        [velocity_pressure] => 4.862
        [Bigtotal_velocity] => 8.72
        [SP2] => 14
        [SP3] => 42
        [SP4] => 41
        [SP5] => 1
        [SP6] => 4
        [SP7] => 4
        [SP8] => 4
        [SP9] => 4
        [SP10] => 1
        [Bigtotal_eff] => 0.43
        [static_eff] => 0.19
        [BigBKW] => 0.547
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Big] => 23.69
        [FAN_MODEL] => 
        [FAN_DIA] => 710
        [FAN_RPM] => 1450
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BigVALUE] => 25.00
        [FAN_CMH] => 10000
        [BigPEAK_POWER] => 6414.48
        [Bigoutlet_velocity] => 7.02
        [velocity_pressure] => 3.014
        [Bigtotal_velocity] => 26.70
        [SP1] => 3
        [SP2] => 4
        [SP3] => 5
        [SP4] => 6
        [SP5] => 7
        [SP6] => 3
        [SP7] => 2
        [SP8] => 1
        [SP9] => 2
        [SP10] => 3
        [Bigtotal_eff] => 0.62
        [static_eff] => 0.55
        [BigBKW] => 1.180
    )

)
```

i have to find nearest value in each set of sp1 to sp10 for array[0]->with STATIC_PRESSURE=0.34,
aray[2]->1
array[3]->23.and so on..
 Please help me out here i m struct.

Answer (score 0):

This searches the highest value in each array keys with name "SPx" where x means a digit, maybe you can built up on this because i dont understand what you mean "with STATIC_PRESSURE=0.34, aray[2]->1 array[3]->23.and so on.."

```
$count = 0;
$max = array();
foreach ($array as $values) { 
        $max[$count] = 0;
    foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
        if(preg_match('/SP\d/', $key)===1){
            if($val>$max[$count]){
                $max[$count] = $val;
            }
        } 
    }
    $count++;    
}
var_dump($max);
```

Comment: i want to find both nearest upper and lower value in each set of sp